# SSRS 2008 Traffic Lights Indicator Showing "Th"

Tags: reporting-services

I implemented a traffic light indicator in my dashboard report in SSRS 2008, but when certain parameter is selected, instead of showing a red-yellow-green light, I see "Th" instead even though the values are properly calculated. Has anyone encountered this?

Comment: What is different about the data returned when you select the "certain parameter"?  My guess would be that the value is not the correct data type for the indicator.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably trying to display an error. If you resize the content you will be able to read the error. I'm using my ESP to predict it is complaining something like "This element has no data to display".

I recommend debugging this by displaying the exact value passed to this traffic light to see what value is breaking it. If you're doing math, make sure you're not dividing by zero or comparing strings to numbers (you can cast your values with math functions like int()).

If this doesn't solve you're issue, post some more details, your expression code and screen shots.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I was able to see the display text once I expand the indicator width and subsequently fixed the bug.

Comment: Nice! Glad I could help.